# $\text{ Proofreading to show all units of }\textbf{Z}\sqrt{-1}\text{ are }\pm1,\pm\sqrt{-1}$

Tags: number-theory

$$\text{Show all the units are }\pm1\text{ and }\pm\sqrt{-1}\text{ in }\textbf{Z}\sqrt{-1}$$
$$\text{Let }\textbf{a+b}\sqrt{-1}\text{ is a unit,}\exists\textbf{ c+d}\sqrt{-1}\in\textbf{Z}\sqrt{-1}$$
$$(\textbf{a+b}\sqrt{-1})(\textbf{c+d}\sqrt{-1})=1$$
$$\Rightarrow norm[(\textbf{a+b}\sqrt{-1})(\textbf{c+d}\sqrt{-1})]=1$$
$$\Rightarrow norm(\textbf{a+b}\sqrt{-1})norm(\textbf{c+d}\sqrt{-1})=1$$
$$\Rightarrow (\textbf{a+b}\sqrt{-1})(\textbf{a-b}\sqrt{-1})(\textbf{c+d}\sqrt{-1})(\textbf{c-d}\sqrt{-1})=1$$
$$\Rightarrow (\textbf{a}^2+\textbf{b}^2)(\textbf{c}^2+\textbf{d}^2)=1$$
$$\Rightarrow (\textbf{a}^2+\textbf{b}^2)=1\text{ and }\textbf{c}^2+\textbf{d}^2=1\text{ or }\textbf{a}^2+\textbf{b}^2=-1\text{ and }\textbf{c}^2+\textbf{d}^2=-1$$
$$\Rightarrow \textbf{a}^2+\textbf{b}^2=\pm1$$
$$\Rightarrow \pm1\textbf{ and }\pm\sqrt{-1}\text{ are units}$$

Comment: Looks fine, but you can save yourself the minus sign in $\;a^2+b^2=\pm1\;$ as this equality happens in $\;\Bbb Z\;$ .

Comment: As Mr.DonAntonio said you will only have $a^2+b^2=1$ as $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ you can not have negative number for sum of two integer squares...you may want to add $a^2+b^2=1$ implies $a^2=1$ and $b^2=0$ or $a^2=0$ and $b^2=0$ which implies $a=\pm 1$ or $b=\pm 1$ which implies $a+b\sqrt{-1}$ is $\pm 1$ or $\pm\sqrt{-1}$